# Why does arp_ignore=1 break ARP on POINTOPOINT interfaces? (kvm guest)

Tags: linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, bridge

If I add the following settings on a kvm guest:

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore=1
```

Networking of the guest stops (highly intermittent).

The kvm host uses bridge-networking:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet6 loopback

auto {{ vbox_interface }}
iface {{ vbox_interface }} inet static
  address {{ vbox_main_ipv4 }}
  netmask {{ vbox_ipv4_netmask }}
  gateway {{ vbox_ipv4_gw }}
  pointopoint {{ vbox_ipv4_gw }}

iface {{ vbox_interface }} inet6 static
  address {{ vbox_main_ipv6 }}
  netmask 128
  gateway {{ vbox_ipv6_gw }}

auto  br0
iface br0 inet static
 address   {{ vbox_main_ipv4 }}
 netmask   255.255.255.255
 bridge_ports none
 bridge_stp off
 bridge_fd 0
 bridge_maxwait 0
{% for ip in vbox_addtl_ipv4 %}
 up route add -host {{ ip }} dev br0
{% endfor %}

iface br0 inet6 static
  address {{ vbox_main_ipv6 }}
  netmask 64
```

Why is that?

As Michael is pointing out in the comments, some context:

- I do understand the basic gist of `arp_ignore` (http://kb.linuxvirtualserver.org/wiki/Using_arp_announce/arp_ignore_to_disable_ARP) - I mainly want to keep that setting as I am in a untrusted network
- I do understand that the setup of network is maybe not standard, this is due to me following this: https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/KVM_mit_Nutzung_aller_IPs_-_the_easy_way/en - which allows me to make usage of all IPs of my given subnet
- I do understand that setting `arp_ignore=0` on the guest VM will solve the issue. However I would like to know why (because I do not need to do that on the host itself) and I can not accept that as answer because I do not believe setting it should cause the network to go offline (e.g. I want to solve the issue without making that setting a dependency)
- I am assuming (thanks Peter Zhabin) that with netmask 255.255.255.255 it is safe enough that nobody within the untrusted network can take advantage of arp?

**So my question I suppose is:**

Why does `arp_ignore=1` break the kvm-guest <> kvm-host networking when the kvm-guest uses pointopoint/255.255.255.255 ?

**Edit 23/10/2018: guest interfaces config**

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens7
iface ens7 inet static
  address IP from the pool {{ vbox_addtl_ipv4 }}
  netmask 255.255.255.255
  gateway {{ vbox_main_ipv4 }}
  pointopoint {{ vbox_main_ipv4 }}

iface ens7 inet6 static
  address xxx::xxx
  netmask 64
  gateway {{ vbox_main_ipv6 }}
```

Comment: Looks like it's because that's what you're asking for. Why are you trying to do that?

Comment: Would it not be safer to have arp_ignore set to 1 in a "untrusted" network? Or in other words: what do I need to do so arp_ignore=1 can be set - to avoid vm guests losing connectivity if that setting is "accidentally" set.

Comment: The only thing that does is to prevent the machine from responding to traffic for that machine that comes in on an interface other than the one to which the IP address is assigned. This may or may not be what you want. Almost always it is not. But you still haven't explained why you are trying to set this despite being asked, so it's impossible to say whether this really will solve [whatever the real problem is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912).

Comment: Thanks Michael, you are right - I added some context and what I am really looking to solve. The main reason for me wanting to rollout `arp_ignore=1` is that I can not trust the network.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to avoid by setting this?

Comment: Spooler: As mentioned above, I am running the server in an untrusted network. I want to avoid the VM-host to ARP that is not coming from its own known interfaces.

Comment: OK, then you definitely do not want this.

Comment: Well, if you don't have any other ARP-capable interfaces on your guests (which for what is available on your posted configs you don't seem to have) there's no point of setting `arp_ignore` to 1, like Michael tried to explain to you. Your current setup creates guest's Ethernet interfaces as `POINTOPOINT`, so the real question is "why does arp_ignore=1 ruins ARP processing on Ethernet POINTOPOINT interfaces". That's an interesting question that requires diggin' linux kernel sources (BTW, what's your kernel version?) and may even yield some bugfixes. But "per se" it doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: @PeterZhabin: thank you for your more detailed information. It is far more helpful than a simple "why do you need" or "why are you trying". I am obviously doing something wrong, but I would like to learn why it is wrong.

Ok, so it makes sense that with a netmask of 255.255.255.255 no arp will be happening on the vm-guest, meaning also the vm-guest should be safe (arp-wise) on an untrusted network.

> BTW, what's your kernel version?

4.9.110-3+deb9u6 / debian 9

Comment: Technically, an ARP-capable interface in P2P mode *should still use ARP*, as  there's no other way for it's endpoints to figure MAC address of the other end. The point is though that if your guest has only one Ethernet interface, setting arp_ignore to 1 effectively does nothing - the kernel should drop ARPs coming from other interfaces whereas you have just one.

Comment: Couldn't an interface in P2P mode simply send everything as Ethernet-level broadcast and enable promiscuous mode on the receive side, if the expectation is that there is only one other endpoint present on the link? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have verified this behavior on Ubuntu 18.04 without any bridges, KVMs or Hetzner whatsoever and I think this is actually a kernel bug with regard to handling of `arp_ignore` on point-to-point Ethernet interfaces. Steps to verify:

1. Make sure `netplan` won't interfere by disabling it altogether.
2. Set up two systems with Ethernet interfaces connected to each other and IP addresses assigned like this:

   Sever A:

   `ip addr add 192.168.100.1/32 peer 192.168.100.2 dev ens33`

   `ip link set ens33 up`

   Server B:

   `ip addr add 192.168.100.2/32 peer 192.168.100.1 dev ens33`

   `ip link set ens33 up`
3. Observe a normal ping from Server A to Server B and `ip addr show` output that contains this line:

   `inet 192.168.100.1 peer 192.168.100.2/32 scope global ens33`
4. Enable `arp_ignore=1` with `sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore=1` on Server A and see pings stopping as soon as ARP entry times out. After certain short amount of time pings *will resume* for a while and then end again. This process will continue indefinitely in this manner.
5. Run a `tcpdump` on Server B and observe inbound pings and outbound endless `who-has` requests for the Server A IP address coming from Server B with no response. Occasionally, Server A will issue `who-has` request for the Server B IP, will get a reply, and Server B will temporarily cache source MAC-address obtained from this ARP request and this is when pings resume.

Now, here's what's going on. There's an in-kernel difference between point-to-point and standard broadcast interfaces in terms of how `iproute2` (and similar tools) populate `in_ifaddr` structure defined in `include/linux/inetdevice.h`.

For normal interfaces it's `ifa_address` field gets populated with *local interface address*; for point-to-point interfaces `ifa_address` gets populated with *remote peer address* and `ifa_local` gets populated with *local interface address*.

This is normal and expected behavior, as in old-school days any point-to-point interface was considered an attached remote device itself; a local endpoint address corresponding to it may not even exist. So nothing is broken here.

What's really broken is that `arp_ignore()` handler defined in `net/ipv4/arp.c` indirectly uses `confirm_addr_indev()` function defined in `net/ipv4/devinet.c` that iteratively tries to match target IP address of the ARP request (that is, local interface address) with `ifa_address` field of all configured IP address records on an interface.

This works well on standard interfaces as they do have their local IP address recorded in `ifa_address` field, however with point-to-point interfaces it fails, 'cause they have peer IP address recorded in this field instead.

Now, the real question is does this issue really need a fix, as it has been pointed out already that there's no sense in using `arp_ignore` on p2p links. I think it does, as there might exist a situation where the host in question has more than one interface (and these interfaces are not p2p ones) and someone might enable this stuff with `conf.all` prefix only to see his p2p links going down for no apparent reason.

Comment: Thanks so much Peter for the detailed answer and replication I am quite (positively) surprised with your knowledge and effort on giving this information.

Comment: Can you please report this bug to kernel developers?

Answer (score -1):

The answer is in the definition:

`arp_ignore -
    0 - (default): reply for any local target IP address, configured
    on any interface
    1 - reply only if the target IP address is local address
    configured on the incoming interface
    2 - reply only if the target IP address is local address
    configured on the incoming interface and both with the
    sender's IP address are part from same subnet on this interface
    3 - do not reply for local addresses configured with scope host,
    only resolutions for global and link addresses are replied
    4-7 - reserved
    8 - do not reply for all local addresses`

Essentially, because the point-to-point interfaces themselves do not have IP addresses assigned, there is no "target ip on the incoming interface".  The IP is assigned to a bridge interface... not to the actual link interface.  And as such, no ARP will be processed.

Comment: Well, this is only true for kvm **host**, whereas OP states that he's setting `arp_ignore=1` on kvm **guest**, where this link is just a standard Ethernet point-to-point interface *with local IP address*.

Comment: It would be useful if he posted a compy of the guest's config... from everything above, it is not unreasonable to assume he also has a bridge interface.  (even if there is only 1 interface in the bridge)

Comment: This might be the case. Few days ago I did a quick dig on a kernel source for any special handling of address scope assignment on p2p Ethernet links and found none, although it was very quick, so I'm might have missed something. The `arp_ignore` in itself is as simple as one `switch` statement and in case of `1` its outcome only depends on address scope.

Comment: I added the guest network interfaces conf.

Comment: I still believe that the host side is not responding to ARPs because of the bridge.  Check on the guest side with an `arp -a` and look for the mac-address of the host.